# Remove View from static Layout? (Nullpointer)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, layout, view

for some reason, I can't remove a view from a static RelativeLayout. The layout is static inside the activity, so i can access it from every View. When i remove e.g. my IntroView via. MainActivity.layout.removeView(this), everything works, but when i do the same with my LevelView (MainActivity.layout.removeView(this)), i get an Nullpointer, that LevelView (or Layout?) is = null, but that's weird because it gets initialized in the onCreate, just like the IntroView, but for some reason it works in the IntroView?

Thanks and i hope you understand what i mean.

```
package catgames.lineland;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.azilen.locationbasedreminder.R;

import catgames.framework.Music;
import catgames.views.HudView;
import catgames.views.IntroView;
import catgames.views.Level1;
import catgames.views.Level2;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // Layout
    public static RelativeLayout layout;

    // Current Screen
    public static String screen;

    // Views
    public static IntroView introview;
    public static HudView hudview;

    // Level
    public static Level1 level1;
    public static Level2 level2;

    // Music
    public static Music music;

    // Context
    public static Context context;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Context
        context = this;

        // Layout
        layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.backdrop);
        setContentView(layout);

        // Level
        introview = new IntroView();
        hudview = new HudView();
        level1 = new Level1();
        level2 = new Level2();

        // Screen
        screen = "IntroView";

        // Layout
        layout.addView(introview);
        layout.addView(hudview);
        layout.addView(level1);

        // Music
        music = new Music(R.raw.music);
        music.setLooping(true);
        music.play();
    }

}
```

Comment: put your code and .xml here

Comment: You might simply hide it instead of remove it to avoid null exception.

Comment: yes i had the same thought, but isn't it better for the performance to remove it? and how do i hide it correctly so onDraw doesn't refresh?

Comment: and btw i don't use .xml, everything is programatally

Comment: Looks more like Layout is null at that point. Post some code mate

Comment: Anyway try to avoid static variables for layout. I'd setup a listener to perform the actions there

Comment: But how can i access it then?

Comment: Please post the actual line of code you are using to remove the view. (MainActivity.layout.removeView(this)) doesn't seem correct.

Comment: From the introview i use MainActivity.layout.removeView(this) and it works, but it doesn't work in level1view

Comment: BTW: Here's the exact error message: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int android.view.View.mViewFlags' on a null object reference

Comment: You should NEVER EVER have a static view. Views only make sense inside of a Context- outside of that Context they don't exist. Having static Views will only lead to bugs, crashes, and memory leaks.  All of those variables should be private, and if other classes need them they should be passed as parameters, NOT accessed statically.  Even if there wasn't a risk of bugs static variables should be minimized, overreliance on statics leads to brittle, hard to debug code.

Comment: I ALWAYS use static vars and it just works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so i just did the following:
this.setVisibility(this.GONE);